# Structure of visualforce page using standard controller, extension and wrapper of data?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, visualforce-component, wrapper-class

I am creating a component to add to a contact record that shows aggregated note data from two different sources.

**Page**

```
<apex:page id="AggergatedNotes"
    standardController="Contact"
    extensions="AggregatedNotesController"
    sideBar="false"
    showHeader="false"
    tabStyle="Contact">
    <c:AggergatedNotes notes="{!wrapper}" />
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class AggregatedNotesController {
    private Case theCase;
    private Contact theContact {get; set;}
    public List<Wrapper> wrappers {get; set;}

    public AggregatedNotesController (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        List<String> Contacts = new List<String>();
        List<Wrapper> wrappers = new List<Wrapper>();

        if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id').startsWith('003') ) {
            this.theContact = (Contact) stdController.getRecord();
            this.parentId = theContact.Id;
            Contacts = Utilities.GetExternalContacts(theContact.Id, 'Ent');
        } else {
            stdController.addFields(new List<String> {'Contact.Id'});
            this.theCase = (Case) stdController.getRecord();
            this.parentId = theCase.Contact.Id;
            Contacts = Utilities.GetExternalContacts(theCase.Contact.Id, 'Ent');
        }
        if (Contacts.size() > 0) {
            List<Event__x> events = [
                SELECT
                OwnerId__r.Name__c,
                OwnerId__r.Id,
                Description__c
                FROM
                Event__x
                WHERE
                WhoId__c IN :Contacts
                ORDER BY EndDateTime__c DESC
            ];

            List<Task__x> tasks = [
                SELECT
                OwnerId__r.Name__c,
                OwnerId__r.Id,
                Description__c
                FROM
                Task__x
                WHERE
                WhoId__c IN :Contacts
                ORDER BY ActivityDate__c DESC
            ];

            for (Event__x ev: events) {
                wrappers.add(new Wrapper(ev) );
            }
            for (Task__x ta: tasks) {
                wrappers.add(new Wrapper(ta) );
            }
        }
    }
    public class Wrapper {
        public Event__x evt {get; set;}
        public Task__x tsk {get; set;}
        public String comments {get; set;}
        public String ownerId {get; set;}
        public String ownerName {get; set;}

        public Wrapper(Task__x t) {
            tsk = t;
            comments = tsk.Description__c;
            ownerId = tsk.OwnerId__r.Id;
            ownerName = tsk.OwnerId__r.Name__c;
        }

        public Wrapper(Event__x e) {
            evt = e;
            comments = evt.Description__c;
            ownerId = evt.OwnerId__r.Id;
            ownerName = evt.OwnerId__r.Name__c;
        }
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
<apex:component id="AggregatedNotes" controller="AggregatedNotesComponentController">
    <apex:attribute name="notes" type="Wrapper" description="The Aggergated Notes List" assignTo="{!wrappers}"/>
   ... Will render table here ...
</apex:component>
```

**Component Controller**

```
public with sharing class AggregatedNotesComponentController {
    // Not sure how to get the wrapper data here
}
```

From what I understand, I need to use the standard controller and then extend my apex class.

Since I am using the two different sources of data, I believe I need to use a wrapper to combine them for my visualforce page.

My main issue is that I don't know now how to pass the data from the page to the component so that I can render it.

Within the component where I assign it to an attribute, it also requires a `type` (`<apex:attribute name="notes" type="..."`) and I wasn't able to get `Wrapper` to work. Unsure what other type this would be.

I'm sure I am way off on this, but hoping to get some feedback on how to approach this structure.

Comment: Because `Wrapper` is an inner-class of `AggregatedNotesController` I believe your Visualforce component will need a type of `AggregatedNotesController.Wrapper`. You can eliminate the verbosity by turning `Wrapper` into its own class.

Comment: @nbrown What would I need to define in `AggregatedNotesComponentController` in order to get access to this from the extended controller? Right now its blank, and this is controller that the component is referencing for that `apex:attribute`.

Comment: Right now you're assigning the `apex:attribute` to `{!wrappers}` but it doesn't exist in your component controller. Create it, and it should be assigned correctly. Check out the Visualforce Component documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_comp_cust_elements_controllers.htm

Comment: @nbrown - Thanks, that's where my confusion is coming from. My page controller has all of that functionality where the wrapper exists. Its either in the wrong place or I need to have it in both I guess.